# How to pickle lxml tree objects and lxml schema objects to binary files and load them

Tags: python-2.7, lxml, pickle, dill

I am trying to pickle (actually using dill) lxml element trees objects and lxml schema objects to binary files, and then load them with dill so I don't have to parse these files every time I run my python script. The XSD schema files are static and they never change. But, I am bumping into the typical problem with pickle (or dill) and that is it not calling the **init** function when I read them back in. I have looked through the python documentation on dill and have read through quite a few programming posts about how to pickle class instances, and load them back in while calling the constructors so you can actually make use of them. If anyone could help me out here I would appreciate it.

```py
from lxml import etree as ET


        for file_type in self.xml_schemas.keys():
              if os.path.isfile(self.xml_schema_files[file_type].replace("xsd", "xso")) and os.path.isfile(self.xml_schema_files[file_type].replace("xsd", "xst")):

                 with open(self.xml_schema_files[file_type].replace("xsd", "xst"), 'rb') as tree_binary_object:
                      self.xsd_trees[file_type] = dill.load(tree_binary_object).__new__(tree_binary_object)

                 with open(self.xml_schema_files[file_type].replace("xsd", "xso"), 'rb') as schema_binary_object:
                      self.xml_schemas[file_type] = dill.load(schema_binary_object).__new__(schema_binary_object)

              else:

                 xsd_tree = ET.parse(self.xml_schema_files[file_type])

                 self.xsd_trees[file_type] = xsd_tree
                 self.xml_schemas[file_type] = ET.XMLSchema(xsd_tree)

                 with open(self.xml_schema_files[file_type].replace("xsd", "xst"), 'wb') as tree_binary_object:
                      dill.dump(self.xsd_trees[file_type], tree_binary_object)

                 **bold**with open(self.xml_schema_files[file_type].replace("xsd", "xso"), 'wb') as schema_binary_object:
                      dill.dump(self.xml_schemas[file_type], schema_binary_object)
```

I am using dictionaries xml_schemas[file_type] that have strings that point to the XSD files, and as you can see, I am replacing the xsd extension with xst to represent the pickled XML schema tree objects, and xso to represent XML schema objects. I am first checking to see if those binary files exist. I am not even sure if I need to pickle the XML schema definition trees. What I really want is an XML schema class object pickled out to a binary file, and then loaded back in and made use of the way you would any lxml schema object to validate XML files. I suppose I might have to subclass lxml.etree.XMLSchema to get this working. If that is the case could someone provide me with some example code? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

### UPDATE

Ok, so, I have managed to pickle the parsed XML Schema definition tree objects. That may be enough to speed up loading of data in my XML validation scripting. So, in response to a comment asking for more code, this is basically what I am currently doing in mt class:

```
import os
import dill
import stat
import pprint
import sys
import string
import re
import copy
from lxml import etree as ET

from utilities import line_parser

class xml_processing_utilities:

      def __init__(self):

          self.xml_schemas_location = "/data/scratch/bbarrett/scripts/python/test_case_validation/develop/maestro_files/xml_schemas/"

          self.xml_schema_files = {}

          self.xml_schema_files["CA"] = self.xml_schemas_location + "maestro_test_case.xsd"
          self.xml_schema_files["TC"] = self.xml_schemas_location + "maestro_test_config.xsd"
          self.xml_schema_files["SN"] = self.xml_schemas_location + "maestro_scenario.xsd"
          self.xml_schema_files["NM"] = self.xml_schemas_location + "maestro_node_mapping.xsd"
          self.xml_schema_files["NC"] = self.xml_schemas_location + "maestro_node_config.xsd"

          self.xml_schemas = {}

          self.xml_schemas["CA"] = None
          self.xml_schemas["TC"] = None
          self.xml_schemas["SN"] = None
          self.xml_schemas["NM"] = None
          self.xml_schemas["NC"] = None

          self.xsd_trees = {}

          self.xsd_trees["CA"] = None
          self.xsd_trees["TC"] = None
          self.xsd_trees["SN"] = None
          self.xsd_trees["NM"] = None
          self.xsd_trees["NC"] = None

          self.get_xml_schemas()

      def initialize_xml_data(self, xml_file, file_type):

          if os.path.isfile(xml_file) and self.file_is_readable(xml_file, -1, ""):
             xml_file_lines = self.read_xml_file_lines(xml_file)
          else:
             return False

          if self.validate_maestro_file_type(file_type, xml_file) != True:
             self.PRINT_COLOR.red("Error: " + xml_file + " is not a valid test case " + file_type + " file. It is missing an opening MAESTRO or SimData XML element at the $
             return False

          passed_syntax_check = True
          line_parser.parser_error_log = []

          parser = line_parser.LineNumberingParser(recover=True)
          parser.feed_lines_last_index = len(xml_file_lines) - 1

          try:
            xml_tree = ET.fromstringlist(xml_file_lines, parser)
          except ET.XMLSyntaxError as lxml_exception:
            pass

          if len(parser.feed_error_log) > 0 or len(line_parser.parser_error_log) > 0:
             passed_syntax_check = False
             self.lxml_error_handler(line_parser.parser_error_log, parser.feed_error_log, file_type, xml_file_lines)

          if not passed_syntax_check:
             return False

          if passed_syntax_check:
             passed_schema_check = True

             schema_validation_errors = None

#############xsd_tree = ET.parse(self.xml_schema_files[file_type])
#############self.xml_schemas[file_type] = self.xsd_trees[file_type]
             xml_schema = ET.XMLSchema(self.xsd_trees[file_type])

             try:
               xml_schema.assertValid(xml_tree)
             except ET.DocumentInvalid as schema_validation_errors:
               pass

             if schema_validation_errors != None and hasattr(schema_validation_errors, 'error_log'):
                self.lxml_error_handler(None, schema_validation_errors.error_log, file_type, xml_file_lines)
                passed_schema_check = False

             if passed_schema_check != True:
                return False


      def get_xml_schemas(self):


          for file_type in self.xml_schema_files.keys():

              if os.path.isfile(self.xml_schema_files[file_type].replace("xsd", "xso")) and os.path.isfile(self.xml_schema_files[file_type].replace("xsd", "xst")):

                 with open(self.xml_schema_files[file_type].replace("xsd", "xst"), 'rb') as tree_binary_object:
                      self.xsd_trees[file_type] = dill.load(tree_binary_object)

#################with open(self.xml_schema_files[file_type].replace("xsd", "xso"), 'rb') as schema_binary_object:
######################self.xml_schemas[file_type] = dill.load(schema_binary_object).__init__(self.xsd_trees[file_type])

              else:

                 self.xsd_trees[file_type] = ET.parse(self.xml_schema_files[file_type])

                 with open(self.xml_schema_files[file_type].replace("xsd", "xst"), 'wb') as tree_binary_object:
                      dill.dump(self.xsd_trees[file_type], tree_binary_object)

#################self.xml_schemas[file_type] = ET.XMLSchema(self.xsd_trees[file_type])

#################with open(self.xml_schema_files[file_type].replace("xsd", "xso"), 'wb') as schema_binary_object:
######################dill.dump(self.xml_schemas[file_type], schema_binary_object)
```

Have no worries about the line_parser. It is just the XMLParser class subclassed to use the feed method on a string list of XML file lines to get the line number so as to tell users on which line they have an XML syntax error.

As you can see, the attempts at pickling (dill) the lxml schema objects have been commented out. When I tried the script with those lines still in the code this is the error message that was thrown by the bombed out Python interpreter:

```
  File "validate_test_case.py", line 174, in <module>
    if ca_file.endswith(".xml") and UTILS.initialize_xml_data(ca_file, "CA") != False:
  File "/data/scratch/bbarrett/scripts/python/test_case_validation/develop/utilities/xml_utilities.py", line 132, in initialize_xml_data
    self.xml_schemas[file_type].assertValid(xml_tree)
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3525, in lxml.etree._Validator.assertValid
  File "src/lxml/xmlschema.pxi", line 111, in lxml.etree.XMLSchema.__call__
```

So, it would be nice to understand how to get that lxml schema object pickled/unpickled as well. Again, thanks to everyone who replies with some advice!

### UPDATE

It just occurred to me that there may not be much of a speed advantage in pickling out the XML schema tree objects, and then loading them back in with pickle. I am seeing that my script is not really faster than when it was building the trees from the schema definition files every time the script was run. If this approach doesn't add much speed in loading XML data, might someone have some suggestions in how to speed things up? I mean, the XML schema files don't change. Might there be some way to store the built XML tree out to disk and then quickly load it back into the lxml etree object after the tree has been written out to a data file? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

### UPDATE

I just discovered a logic error in my code. It was always building the tree due to leaving a check in for .xso (XML Schema Object) files, which is the abandoned effort to pickle the lxml schema definiton objects. So, the code is now as below:

```
      def initialize_xml_data(self, xml_file, file_type):

          if os.path.isfile(xml_file) and self.file_is_readable(xml_file, -1, ""):
             xml_file_lines = self.read_xml_file_lines(xml_file)
          else:
             return False

          if self.validate_maestro_file_type(file_type, xml_file) != True:
             self.PRINT_COLOR.red("Error: " + xml_file + " is not a valid test case " + file_type + " file. It is missing an opening MAESTRO or SimData XML element at the $
             return False

          passed_syntax_check = True
          line_parser.parser_error_log = []

          parser = line_parser.LineNumberingParser(recover=True)
          parser.feed_lines_last_index = len(xml_file_lines) - 1

          try:
            xml_tree = ET.fromstringlist(xml_file_lines, parser)
          except ET.XMLSyntaxError as lxml_exception:
            pass

          if len(parser.feed_error_log) > 0 or len(line_parser.parser_error_log) > 0:
             passed_syntax_check = False
             self.lxml_error_handler(line_parser.parser_error_log, parser.feed_error_log, file_type, xml_file_lines)

          if not passed_syntax_check:
             return False

          if passed_syntax_check:
             passed_schema_check = True

             schema_validation_errors = None

#############xsd_tree = ET.parse(self.xml_schema_files[file_type])
#############self.xml_schemas[file_type] = self.xsd_trees[file_type]
             xml_schema = ET.XMLSchema(self.xsd_trees[file_type])

             try:
               xml_schema.assertValid(xml_tree)
             except ET.DocumentInvalid as schema_validation_errors:
               pass

             if schema_validation_errors != None and hasattr(schema_validation_errors, 'error_log'):
                self.lxml_error_handler(None, schema_validation_errors.error_log, file_type, xml_file_lines)
                passed_schema_check = False

             if passed_schema_check != True:
                return False


      def get_xml_schema_trees(self):

          for file_type in self.xml_schema_files.keys():

#############if os.path.isfile(self.xml_schema_files[file_type].replace("xsd", "xst")):

#############with open(self.xml_schema_files[file_type].replace("xsd", "xst"), 'rb') as tree_binary_object:
###################self.xsd_trees[file_type] = dill.load(tree_binary_object)

 ############with open(self.xml_schema_files[file_type].replace("xsd", "xso"), 'rb') as schema_binary_object:
 #################self.xml_schemas[file_type] = dill.load(schema_binary_object).__init__(self.xsd_trees[file_type])

##########else:

              self.xsd_trees[file_type] = ET.parse(self.xml_schema_files[file_type])

##########with open(self.xml_schema_files[file_type].replace("xsd", "xst"), 'wb') as tree_binary_object:
###################dill.dump(self.xsd_trees[file_type], tree_binary_object)

#####################self.xml_schemas[file_type] = ET.XMLSchema(self.xsd_trees[file_type])

#########with open(self.xml_schema_files[file_type].replace("xsd", "xso"), 'wb') as schema_binary_object:
##################dill.dump(self.xml_schemas[file_type], schema_binary_object)
```

So, basically, I am not even trying to pickle. Might as well remove the function to attempt the pickling. If anybody could help me with pickling these lxml objects, I would be very grateful.

Comment: How can we reproduce the problem? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I see that you updated the question, but I don't really understand what the problem is.

Comment: Maybe it would just be easier at this point to state what I am trying to do. I want to pickle out an lxml XMLSchema object, and then read it back into a lxml XMLSchema object. I am hitting the typical problem of Python complaining about the object not being initialized whe n I read the object back in and try to use it. I have come across a number of questions to this effect here on stackoverflow, but they all involve user defined class objects that are not as involved as an lxml tree or schema object, and I don't really understand how to translate those answers into what I am trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. What do you mean by "typical problem"? IMHO, the best you can do now is to put some effort into providing a proper [mcve] (as I have already suggested).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give the `xmlschema` library a go. Looks like schemas loaded using that library can be pickled without problem.